# MacTex different chapter margins in different cases

Tags: margins, chapters, mactex

I'm totally newbie in TeX and looking for help.

I need to configure chapter styles according to requirements given by my university. It requires chapter to have top margin of 18pt and of 36pt if it is at the beginning go the new page. I figured out how to set top margin to 18pt:

```
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{18pt}{12pt}
```

Unfortunately it does not work, as I'm using my own command for chapters:

```
\newcommand\Chapter[1]{
    \refstepcounter{chapter}
    \chapter*{
        \begin{center}
            \begin{Large}
                \chaptername\ \arabic{chapter}. \MakeUppercase{#1}          
            \end{Large}
        \end{center}
    }
}
```

And it has very large spacing. I tried to use

```
\titlespacing*{chapter*}{0pt}{18pt}{12pt}
```

but it fails with error:

```
Missing \endcsname inserted.
```

So, the question is, how to make my own chapter command have different top margins if it is at the page start and if it is not? If it is not possible, just how to make it to have margins not so large?

UPD:
Here's what I need to achieve:
Chapter title at page start:
[image: 36pt margin]

Chapter title somewhere in the page:
[image: 18pt margin]

Comment: So your chapters needn't start a new page?

Comment: The argument to `\chapter` or `\chapter*` should not have any font or alignment command in it. It is supposed to be the _title_. The formatting of chapter titles should be specified elsewhere (either in the document class or the preamble)

Comment: `\Large` is a font *switch*. There is no `Large` environment (unless you've defined it).

Comment: What do you mean by 'top margin' in the two cases? Normally, this is the margin at the top of the page, before the text body. So it doesn't apply in the middle of the page at all.

Comment: @egreg Well, this is a requirement for the chapter title. And there is no requirement for chapters to start a new page every time or not. So, it is not possible to make different margins in these cases?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see, but in this case how can I modify title's font and margins in a correct way?

Comment: @cfr I've redefined font sizes for `\Large` like this: `\renewcommand\large{\@setfontsize\large{15.5}{17}}

\renewcommand\Large{\@setfontsize\Large{16.5}{19}}` I've updateg the topic to show what I mean by 'top margin'

Comment: @cfr all commands can be used as enviroments (although you need some care to use a font switch as an environment as you need a paragraph break, but same is true if you use `{\large ....}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah. OK. I think somebody mentioned that before. Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a link to the question that makes the university specs available for us? In english of course.